# На долго ли хватало 10 МБ памяти жесткого диска в 1980 году?

Tags: память, история

На долго ли хватало 10 МБ памяти жесткого диска в 1980 году?
Сколько информационного пространства занимала программа или игра? (медиа файлы в расчет не беру)

Comment: Надолго. У меня в конце 1990-х была дискетка на 1,4Мб, до сих пор не до конца заполнена.  А уж 10 мег в 1980 хватало на вечность и еще больше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотря для чего. В целом - да, надолго.

Если брать за источник Википедию, то в 1980 году выбор персональных компьютеров был совсем невелик. Вот несколько из них:

- [Atari 400/800/XL/XE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_400/800/XL/XE) (10 КБ ПЗУ)
- [ZX80](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80) (4 КБ ПЗУ)
- [TRS-80 Color Computer](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Color_Computer) (8 КБ ПЗУ)

10 Мб - это в 1,000 раз больше, чем объём Atari 400/800/XL/XE.

---

Если говорить про перенос информации, то тогда лидировали дискеты.

На дискету 5¼ можно было записать 110, 360, 720 или 1200 Кб данных.
Несложно посчитать, что максимальный объём примерно в 10 раз меньше названного Вами.

Также в 1980 г. как раз появился на свет первый жёсткий диск форм-фактора 5,25 дюйма.
Это был [ST-506](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ST-506) от Seagate объёмом в 5 Мб.

---

Если говорить про игровую индустрию, то стоит выделить картриджи.

Их объём можно сравнивать с объёмом дискет, то есть примерно до Мб.

Comment: Эх Атари, до сих пор у родителей где-то в ящиках лежит. В нем был вшит какой-то бейсик. Жалко, что сохранить программу было некуда и при выключении все пропадало.

Answer (score 3):

1980г. Эпоха персональных компьютеров еще не наступила. За рубежом в 70-е годы нарастает бум на микропроцессоры и микро-ЭВМ, пока еще преобладают 8-разрядные. Для серьезных приложений используются мэйнфреймы и мини-ЭВМ. Причем функционируют они, как правило, в режиме коллективного пользования. Пользователи работают в лучшем случае с видеотерминала, а в СССР - чаще в пакетном режиме, с колодой перфокарт. В качестве съемных носителей информации используются магнитные ленты и пакеты магнитных дисков (НМД емкостью 7 Мбайт и 29 Мбайт). Это очень большой объем по тем временам, ведь общий объем ОЗУ для серии ЕС ЭВМ (отечественный аналог мэйнфрейма IBM 360) варьировался от 64 Кбайт до 512 Кбайт, в зависимости от модели. И для выполнения программы пользователя отводилось едва ли 10% от этого объема. Ленты и диски использовались, в основном, для хранения массивов данных. Пакетом магнитных дисков пользовались тогда коллективно годами.